# asp.net MVC GridView Alternatives for Displaying Data

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET MVC and am going through the NerdDinner tutorial.  As I'm going through I'm trying to apply what I see with how I will develop my site.  I have experience with WinForms and much of what I'm wanting to do is display large amounts of data contained in a database.

I have used `DataGridView` along with `DataSets` and `DataTable` accessing SQLite databases.  Going through the NerdDinner tut I see mainly access to SQL Server through Linq to SQL and generating HTML tables rather than using ASP.NET Web UI Components such as GridView.

I like most of the functions and look that the Web UI Components can bring, but I'm not sure if they are necessary.  How do you all decide when displaying lots of data from databases what display components to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/documentation) has a lot of great things to aid with ASP.NET MVC development.  In this case the [Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation) would help you a lot.  I've used it in the past and found it to be pretty slick.

If you're using jQuery as well, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2009/03/28/walkthrough-full-example-of-using-mvccontrib-grid-with-jquery-datatable.aspx) talks about integrating it with the jQuery datable--makes paging and sorting essentially no-effort/painless.

Comment: Does the gridview referring have a property that makes the gridview column headers to be frozen and griddata to be scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

By experience with MVC and ASP .Net Control, your better not user control in a ASP Web form application.

The point is that they work with view state that is against the pattern of MVC.

In the case of your `DataGridView` what I would do is to loop through the list with a `foreach` and output a table row.

Comment: I was hoping to have a solution that could provide a Table/Grid that provides basic functions like moving columns, changing data, etc..  Are there nataive HTML tags that can allow this sort of customization?

Comment: For sort of "grid" way to manage data in the html part, I never have any experience. You better try the solution of @Jacob or @ataddeini. But i got a preference for @Jacob beacuse it base on Jquery and recommande by Phil Haack.

Answer (score 2):

[Phil Haack](http://haacked.com) has a good post of [using the jQuery Grid plugin](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) with MVC to create a more "out of the box" grid solution like what you would be used to with the ASP.NET controls you mention.

[image]